# How do I get a random subreddit image to my discord.py bot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, praw

I am making a discord bot in async python.
I want the bot to post a **random** picture when I do a command (prefix !) example !meme. This would bring up a random picture from a subreddit, in this case the memes subreddit. I have made the start to what I want, but I need help with the random subreddit bit.

```py
import discord
import praw
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(description="test", command_prefix="!")

@bot.command()
async def meme():
    await bot.say(---)   
    #--- WOULD BE THE REDDIT URL
    bot.run("TOKEN")
```

**How would I do this, using discord.py and PRAW?**

Comment: I would start by writing some code, and if you have a *specific* programming question, then coming and asking here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code will fetch a random post from the memes subreddit. Currently it picks a random submission from the top 10 posts from the hot section.

```
import praw
import random
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(description="test", command_prefix="!")

reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='CLIENT_ID HERE',
                     client_secret='CLIENT_SECRET HERE',
                     user_agent='USER_AGENT HERE')

@bot.command()
async def meme():
    memes_submissions = reddit.subreddit('memes').hot()
    post_to_pick = random.randint(1, 10)
    for i in range(0, post_to_pick):
        submission = next(x for x in memes_submissions if not x.stickied)

    await bot.say(submission.url)

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

Comment: @AlexWollan Go here https://www.reddit.com/prefs/apps and create an app

Comment: I've tested the code and it works fine. Make sure your client_id, client_secret and user_agent are correct. Quick start guide here: https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/quick_start.html

Comment: Like this? USER_AGENT="WHAT I NAMED MY SCRIPT" @Benjin

Answer (score -1):

```
@client.command(aliases=['Meme'])
async def meme(ctx):
    reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='XXXX',
                        client_secret='XXXX',
                        user_agent='XXXX')

    submission = reddit.subreddit("memes").random()
    await ctx.send(submission.url)
```