# Is there a better way to get a submission from a subreddit?

Tags: python, reddit, praw

Is there a better way to get a submission one at a time sorting by hot in a subreddit without repeating rather than having a for loop go through all of the previous submissions in the praw library for Reddit API as it feels a bit inefficient when you go to a large number of posts I found in this question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49881935/how-do-i-get-a-random-subreddit-image-to-my-discord-py-bot)

Answer (score 0):

You can consume the reddit API directly https://www.reddit.com/dev/api